# Difference model between two raster (DEM) how to show values bigger than and smaller than 0,00

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, raster-calculator

I got to DEM layers over the same area with positive and negative values in them. So I ran a raster calculator raster1-raster2. 
Now the raster got values with 0,000659 (This should be counted as 0,00, I just want 2 decimals) and so on. 
I would just like to display values that are bigger or smaller than 0,00 either by symbology or by doing a new calcuation and extracting all values that are not equal to 0,00.

Using Qgis

Comment: Did you try using a `round()` function in your computations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your DEM layers have the names `DEM1` and `DEM2`.
The following expression (in the QGIS *Raster Calculator*) returns 0 for the differences that have an absolute value that is less than 0.005, and the calculated difference larger absolute differences:

> "DEM1@1" - "DEM1@1" * (("DEM1@1" - "DEM1@1" > 0.005) OR ("DEM1@1" - "DEM1@1" < -0.005))

Comment: This workt perfect. Thank you!